# Firefox CSS URL problems

Tags: css, firefox

Files:
 - /default.htm 
 - /theme/styletest.css 
 - /theme/images/bb1.png

/theme/styletest.css content

```
.test{
  width:200px; height:50px;
  background-image:url('images/bb1.png');
}
```

It works in all browsers other than Firefox, and looks a background image.

---

/theme/styletest.css content

```
.test{
  width:200px; height:50px;
  background-image:url('theme/images/bb1.png');
}
```

Only works in Firefox

How do I make it work in all browsers? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It should work in all the browser. do you have any live url to show this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your original code with very simple files. `images/bb1.png` works with Firefox and Chrome. `theme/images/bb1.png` doesn't work for both.

So, the problem is not related to CSS. Please give us the html code of default.htm. I guess some approximative/buggy syntax somewhere changes the paths understood by Firefox.

Also, what is your version of Firefox ?

Comment: I found the problem. Errors caused me.
Broken line: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tema\ana.css"/>
The correct line: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tema/ana.css"/>
Resolved to do the right

Comment: Ah, fine. That's why it's important to give the whole code even if it seems not directly related to the problem : otherwise we need to test and guess about absent files just like I did. Can you please add a check to the answer as the problem is resolved ?